# How do I capture what a user puts in a web form and use it to calculate another number with some jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, webforms

How do I capture what a user puts in a web form and use it to calculate another number with some jquery?

I would like to  capture a number that a user enters into a web form. When they hit "NEXT" the number will be multiplied by a constant (which depends on which service they select in another form field) and then presented on the web page using jquery I think the .change jquery function could be used for that.

thanks for any advice with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<h2>Product:</h2>
<select id="product">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<h2>Quantity:</h2>
<input type="number" id="quantity" />
<h2>Result:</h2>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
$('#quantity,#product').bind('change keyup', function() {
    var product = $('#product').val(),
        quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val(),10),
        result = product * quantity;
    $('#result').text(result);
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rVe6R/3/

The above does not use a *next* button, instead it uses the change and keyup events. Below is another version with a *next* button.

```
<h2>Product:</h2>
<select id="product">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
    <option value="4">Four</option>
</select>
<h2>Quantity:</h2>
<input type="number" id="quantity" />
<h2>Result:</h2>
<span id="result"></span>
<br />
<button id="trigger" value="next">Next</button>
<script>
$('#trigger').click(function() {
    var product = $('#product').val(),
        quantity = parseInt($('#quantity').val(),10),
        result = product * quantity;
    $('#result').text(result);
});
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rVe6R/4/

Answer (score 1):

I would pull the value of the text field in the click event of the "next" button... I think something like this would work:

```
$('#btnNext').click(function(){
     var yourConstant = 10;
     var newVal = $('#usrValue').val() * yourConstant;

     //display result
     $('#divResult').html(newVal);
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/QTJ62/